# Unable to retrieve classes ttd

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp website solution where i wish to add some unit tests.

In the solution i have added a new test project.

All my C# classes are located in the folder called 'App_Code'.

But when i try to write `Person p = new Person();` in my test class it cannot find the class Person.

Its my intention to make that object and fill it up with all sorts of things the person class holds (id, name etc).

```
//But i wish to directly acces Person, not PersonTest  
    PersonTest pt = new PersonTest();

                pt.IdTest = 1; //error method group only
```

How can i exactly put test date into the ID? Ms Test is pretty confusing compared to JUnit where everything seemed alot more straight forward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the "using" directive?  After adding the reference, you also either have to reference classes by `namespace.class`, or add a `using personnamespace;` at the top of the file.

Comment: I have thought about that but with no succees. I only have 3 options: system, microsoft and TTD. But nowhere the namespace that i wish to use (of my main project that is). Regards.

Comment: Can you add your reference by choosing "Add Reference -> Browse" and selecting the physical path of the class?

Comment: If i add reference to my main project the TTD namespace is there (since i auto generated test classes for every c# class thats located in app_code). But i cannot add a reference when i click on the TTD project for my main project. No idea what i am doing wrong here, i cannot acces my classes in the UnitTests.

Comment: The problem is when i add new test it automaticly adds a new project (although on the same solution). But then i cannot acces the classes, how can i add unit tets directly in my project? Because i am also using subversion and messing with all those solutions is nothing but problems. Ive had it generated inside my project but then i had to many subversion errors i had to start over, although no idea how i pulkled it off.  Best Regards.

Comment: You could just move the PersonTest.cs to your project, but I think there are a lot of good reasons to keep them in a seperate project.

Comment: Try closing VS, removing all the references and then re-adding them -- if the projects are in the same solution, they have to be available as a reference.  Then make sure to add the "using" directive.

Comment: Ive noticed i did not have a namespace in the app_code map so i set that right. Although when i add a new unit test the using.AppCode is red colored in my test class. And i can still not acces the Person class. I must be a very minor thing remaining. What purpose has the TestContext method? Thanks.

Comment: Now rebuild your AppCode class.  That should create the object reference and you should then be able to add the reference in your test project and the red underline should go away in your using directive.  TextContext is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245541.aspx

Comment: Hm i am getting the following error Error 1 Source file 'C:\...\MainProject\TTD\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') TTD. Its just absurd my main project can lay a reference to TTD but not the other way around? If i add a unit i can see all the classes and it get/set methods, so when i click it the tests get AUTO generated. But then it suddenly cannot find the namespace App_code.

Comment: Does this file exist?  Now that you added the namespace to your AppCode, you might try deleting your TTD and recreating a TestProject.

Comment: Thanks alot for the given efford but guess il try to look up on Nunit, this has taken enough of my time. It still displays Using App-Code in red (although no more error) Best Regards.

Comment: Much appreciated but its mainly to start learning TTD, so if i cannot do it myself it does not have much point. Thanks again though Jess.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the proper references setup to access your code. Right click on References in your Test project -> Add Reference -> Projects tab -> Choose the project where "Person" is.

Comment: Add reference --> Project Tab is empty although its in the same solution? If i check the references in my main solution it has the TTD project namespace, but not the other way around. I already had all the test auto generate for each class...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but in a winform project. In my case the answer was I had misspelt the namespace. As soon as I changed that it came up.
Allen